# About partition of harddisk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I had 320GB hard disk which had 5 partitions C:95GB,D:60GB,E:60GB,F:24GB,G:48GB.
I was installing ubuntu 8.0 before 3yrs it would show correct path to install or separate partition to install.Now in Ubuntu 14.0 i tried of installing it took all the partitions and made as single C:298GB disk.All my Partitions are lost.All data are also lost.
What can i do now to recover partition please help.

Comment: I did this one time with windows it deleted my other partitions, however I had backups. keeping backups can save you in a time when something like this happens